# How to give gravity for child views inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am working on `ConstraintLayout`, I can adjust the child views, but I can't  align the `Textview` from left to right. Is there any way to align the `Textview` from left to right?

Here is the code:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mylotslist_itemview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lotnumber"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sellername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="ffffffffff"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lotstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/lot_statusfalse"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding5"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding5"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding5"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="Alloted and Empty"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.66"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createddate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"

        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="01-FEB-2018 10:30 AM"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want my textview to be aligned like this. Is there any possible way to 
align like this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` from all your views except first one.because it's will assign your all views in left.

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mylotslist_itemview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lotnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/serialnumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sellername"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="ffffffffff"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lotnumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lotstatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Alloted and Empty"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sellername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createddate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="01-FEB-2018 10:30 AM"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lotstatus"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: yes but I want my textview to take fixed size Because i dnt want to it to affect another view on the layout I have implemented the way you have mentioned.But when the content of the text increases the textview to the right side of the view also moving away.

Comment: use `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` so you can set width in percentage to your views and  it's would not increase size of view

Comment: Thank you for this what I am looking for

Comment: This solved my problem! `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Answer (score 2):

Set constraint, for example:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

and use this (value from 0 - left to 1 - right)

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` from all views except first one and also add `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf = "@+id/your_left_views_id"` for each view except first one.

like

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mylotslist_itemview"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lotnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
    android:text="50"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/serialnumber"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sellername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
    android:text="ffffffffff"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lotnumber"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lotstatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding5"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding5"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding5"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding5"
    android:text="Alloted and Empty"
    android:textColor="@color/white"

    android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.66"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sellername"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createddate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
    android:text="01-FEB-2018 10:30 AM"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lotstatus"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are giving to all views
> app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
> app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" this is wrong.
>
> In constraint layout you have to give start,end,top,bottom constraint to related view.
>
> try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mylotslist_itemview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serialnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/color_btn_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lotnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="@color/color_charcoal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/serialnumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/serialnumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sellername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="ffffffffff"
        android:textColor="@color/radius_text_blue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lotnumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/serialnumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lotstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue_text"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="Alloted and Empty"
        android:textColor="@color/default_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sellername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/serialnumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createddate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@color/file_limit_error"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
        android:text="01-FEB-2018 10:30 AM"
        android:textColor="@color/default_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_itemtextsize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lotstatus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/serialnumber" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

1. Add constraints (top + bottom or start + end)
2. Set android:layout_width="0dp" (for start-end relations), or
   android:layout_height="0dp" (for top-bottom relations)

Now, your child view has constraints to related parent view and its gravity starts from start (or else, what you defined with android:gravity="" tag).